# Help with Time Series prediction

Tags: time-series, lstm, rnn, prediction

I'm a complete n00b to both this stackexchange and ML so please don't flame me too bad.

I am trying to make a prediction from Time Series data.
I have about 10 years worth of 1-minute resolution price data for the S&P500. What I'd like to do is treat each DAY in the data as it's own series to predict what the price movement will be for the last 15 minutes of market hours.

I've looked through several books, some tutorials and a lot of articles. I've been trying to leverage an LSTM RNN model for these predictions. The problem, I think, is that all the examples I've been following (whether univariate or multivariate) treat the time series data as a single time series. What I would like to do is treat each day as a time series and try to predict today's final movements based on the past 10 years or daily stock price.

Am I hopelessly far off here? Is this not even the right problem to try to solve with ML?

Anything that could point me in the right direction would be incredibly appreciated!
TIA

Comment: Hello Ramy ! Could you telle more about sentence "treat the time series data as a single time series" ? For Recurrent neural networks, it is highly recommended to train your model on a large number of sequences (meaning fixed-size subsets of different time series).

Comment: Sure! So it would be possible to consider each day as it's own timeseries. It's ALSO possible to consider the entire set of days as ONE time series. In a way, it would be ideal to combine the concepts because each day's prices is, at least slightly, influenced by the previous day's prices. Not sure if that answers your question.

Comment: Yes ! When using RNN-LSTM, you have to extract fixed-size sub-sequences from one or multiple time series. For example, If you have M time series containing each N timesteps and you want to create sub-sequences of size 10, you can extract up to M x (N-10) sub-sequences to fit your model. More here : https://machinelearningmastery.com/prepare-univariate-time-series-data-long-short-term-memory-networks/

Comment: ok yes. this makes sense. so if I have about 3000 days worth of data and each day has 391 observations and each observation is Open price, High price, Low price and Close price I would want my data to have the shape (3000,391,4), right? How do I delineate each day into it's own train/validate/test sets? Everything I've seen splits the  data by changing the FIRST element of the shape. Is it possible to change the 2nd element into three groups? I haven't seen an example of that just yet.